# Javascript asynch await on a waterfall sequence

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Sorry for this beginner question. I have read multiple documentations and several online tutorials. I'm still stuck with asynchroneous.

My goal to achieve is to have func6 to wait for func5 to complete before starting to execute.
Knowing that func5 is containing a sub-function that last some undefined time.

In the following piece of code, the waterfall sequence works not as expected and I have this messy example where I stand now :

```
let async = require("async");

function func1(payload, options, chainOrder, callback) {
    payload.logs = {};
    payload.logs.func1 = true;
    chainOrder.push("func 1");
    callback(null, payload, undefined, chainOrder);
}
function func2(payload, object, chainOrder, callback) {
    payload.logs.func2 = true;
    chainOrder.push("func 2 and 4");
    callback(null ,payload, object, chainOrder);
}
function func3(payload, object, chainOrder, callback) {
    payload.logs.func3 = true;
    chainOrder.push("func 3");
    callback(null, payload, object, chainOrder);
}
function func4(payload, object, chainOrder, callback) {
    payload.logs.func4 = true;
    chainOrder.push("func 4");
    callback(null, payload, object, null, chainOrder);
}
function func5(payload, fields, current_flow, chainOrder, callback) {
    payload.logs.func5 = true;
    chainOrder.push("func 5");
    func5_sub_function();
    callback(null, payload, fields, current_flow, chainOrder);
}
function func6(payload, fields, current_flow, chainOrder, callback) {
    payload.logs.func6 = true;
    chainOrder.push("func 6");
    callback(null, payload, fields, current_flow, chainOrder);
}
function func7(payload, fields, current_flow, chainOrder, callback) {
    payload.logs.func7 = true;
    chainOrder.push("func 7");
    callback(null, payload, fields, current_flow, chainOrder);
}
function func8(payload, fields, current_flow, chainOrder, callback) {
    payload.logs.func8 = true;
    chainOrder.push("func 8");
    callback(null, payload, fields, current_flow, chainOrder);
}
function func9(payload, fields, current_flow, chainOrder, callback) {
    payload.logs.func9 = true;
    chainOrder.push("func 9");
    callback(null, payload, fields, current_flow, chainOrder);
};

async function processAll(payloads, options, res) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.debug("processAll in a chain");
        let result = [];
        payloads.map(async function(p) {
            let chainOrder = [];
            console.debug("--------", "chaining", result.length+1 +" item(s).");
            async.waterfall([
                async.apply(func1, p, options, chainOrder),
                func2,
                func3,
                func2,
                func4,
                func5,
                func6,
                func7,
                func8,
                func9,
            ], function (err, response) {
                if( response && !err ) {
                    let measure = response.fields;
                    let payload = response.payload;
                    chainOrder.map((chain, index) => {
                        console.debug("chain end", index, chain);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

func5_sub_function = async function(flow, payload, listPreprocessor) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("func5_sub_function is using 2 secs");
            resolve( {payload, foo: false, bar: 123} );
        }, "2000");
    })
}

let run_test = function(my_payload, my_options) {
    processAll(my_payload, my_options).then( (payload) => {
        console.debug("processAll completed");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error on processAll: ", err);
        console.debug("Precondition failed");
    });
}

run_test( [{value: 1}], {foo: 123, bar: 456} );
```

Any advice would be helpfull. Thanks.

Comment: Well you're not waiting for `func5_sub_function();` before you call the callback. You'll need to write either `await func5_sub_function(); callback(…)` or `func5_sub_function().then(() => callback(…));`.

Comment: Btw you really should get rid of the *async.js* library and just write modern code with `async`/`await` syntax. Instead of taking callbacks, return promises (or just write a synchronous function if it doesn't do anything asynchronous), and instead of the `async.waterfall(…)` just write `func1(); func2(); func3(); func4(); await func5(); func6(); …`

Comment: Such tasks can be accomplished with e.g. [iterating over async generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of#iterating_over_async_generators) with [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of).

Comment: @PeterSeliger I don't see how a generator is needed here. Just a normal `async function` will suffice, no async iteration.

Comment: @Bergi ... I assumed that the OP was talking about a generic way/approach where from a pool of async functions always the next function (from/of a specific function precedence) gets invoked as soon as the promise of the then current async function settles.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Even in that case, just write `for (const fn of asyncFunctionsPool) { await fn(); }`, don't use an async iterator

Comment: @Bergi ... thanks for clarifying the latter.